# Is `user` equal to `new User(user.toObject())` or is there hidden magic properties?

Tags: mongoose

Is `user` equal to `new User(user.toObject())` or is there hidden magic properties?

Doesn't need to pass a `==` or `===` check, just need to make sure that it doesn't create a new document in the db.